# Is Medibuntu needed - or even desirable?

Tags: medibuntu

Recently I started having a problem when checking for updates: the process stalled for several minutes while connecting to the medibuntu site.  This happened every time. (Mysteriously, this only happened on one of my two computers.)  Getting tired of this, I unchecked Medibuntu in my software sources, and everything speeded up again.

Is this something I will regret?  I have some things installed from Medibuntu, but once installed do I get anything by getting updates from Medibuntu?  Or are things now provided elsewhere - like in Multiverse - sufficiently now so that I no longer need Medibuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in recent versions of Ubuntu, multiverse repository contains most of the required packages. But, some enhanced codecs are not include due to licensing issue. *(Because they are not free, as freedom)*. Those packages are maintained by medibuntu repostiory.

> Is this something I will regret?

No, actually. If you already installed all the necessary codecs. Because, medibuntu repository updates once for a single release. See [this](http://packages.medibuntu.org/).

> Are things now provided elsewhere - like in Multiverse - sufficiently now so that I no longer need Medibuntu?

Though, multiverse contain most of the packages, it still missing some. For example, you can't find [these packages](http://packages.medibuntu.org/precise/index.html) named with `extra`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the PPA or Repository active then you will get any updates they make. If you have it disabled then you will be left with whatever you downloaded from them. It will not create any problem if you disable or remove the repository since you have already downloaded what you need it. The only thing is that any updates to their repository will not be reflected as updates in your PC (Since you do not have the repository active of course).

Now for the question as such, the packages in 11.10 and am guessing future versions have most if not all needed codecs and multimedia packages needed for everything to work correctly.

It is common now to install the `ubuntu-restricted-addons` and `ubuntu-restricted-extras` (It is so common that the installer gives you that option to select) and get many of the packages that medibuntu has. And if there are any missing you can find them in the repositories of Ubuntu without the need to add medibuntu. For example mencoder, the dvd authoring stuff, etc..

Comment: I did install the restricted addons and extras when I installed Ubuntu, and then later added Medibuntu - following the advice of several sites - and all has gone well.  So, if many of those packages are increasingly available from other repositories, is Medibuntu sort of going away, at least for the latest versions of Ubuntu?