# The Medibuntu Project has come to an end - what do I do now?

Tags: medibuntu

[The Medibuntu Project has come to an end](http://www.medibuntu.org/): what do I do now?

- How do I find packages on my system which came from medibuntu? The [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223179/how-to-remove-medibuntu-rrep-and-packages) seems to list medibuntu packages explicitly - is there a way to query the package database by the source?
- Do I need to remove them so that they are replace by maintained packages from other sources?
- Which repository contains those packages now?

Comment: Related: as it is what to do about one of the packages, http://askubuntu.com/questions/356046/i-cant-install-libdvdread4-due-the-script-not-finding-the-medibuntu-repositorie

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85397/is-medibuntu-needed-or-even-desirable

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By now almost all the medibuntu packages have been already superseded with packages from the main repos (restricted, universe, multiverse), so the task is to eliminate the *traces* of medibuntu.

You would probably be better off installing `aptitude` before hand (see below).

As `root`, do the following to forget medibuntu:

```
aptitude purge medibuntu-keyring
rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
aptitude update
```

Now, to purge the packages which come from medibuntu, do this:

```
aptitude purge $(dpkg-query -W -f='${PackageSpec}\t${Maintainer}\n' '*' |\
  grep medibuntu-maintainers@lists.launchpad.net |\
  cut -f1)
```

You might have to select an alternative dependency problem resolution (e.g., `aptitude` might suggest that you remove a 100 packages if you purge a medibuntu library `libavutil`; say `no` and it will offer to install the same library from an alternative source).

This means that you will probably be better off using `aptitude` than `apt-get` for this task because the former offers the alternatives for dependency problem resolution.  See also

- [Aptitude vs. apt-get: Which is the recommended (aka the “right”) tool to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use)
- [Is aptitude still considered superior to apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get)

Comment: You'll either need to install aptitude first (`sudo apt-get install aptitude`) or use `apt-get`. Aptitude doesn't exist by default.

Comment: The 'cut' command is wrong as the delimiter is a space, use this instead: aptitude purge $(dpkg-query -W -f='${PackageSpec} ${Maintainer}\n' '*' |\ grep medibuntu-maintainers@lists.launchpad.net |\ cut -f1 -d' ')

Comment: @tdk: I fixed the command differently.

Comment: The most important part of the question has not been answered: "Which repository contains those packages now?"

Comment: @Mephisto: By now almost all the medibuntu packages have been already superseded with packages from the main repos (restricted, universe, multiverse), so the task is to eliminate the traces of medibuntu

Comment: **aptitude is not installed by default** in Ubuntu. Can a user install a package (aptitude) if he/she has already a corrupted repository ? Will apt-get let him/her to install anything at all ?

Comment: @NikTh: please ask this as a separate question.

Comment: OK, what NikTh is telling you that your answer should **install aptitude first** before you can start using it ;).

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: Now you edited your answer the downvote(mine) became an Upvote :-)