# "Failed to load the package list" - fixes posted not working

Tags: server, package-management

I have a pretty new installation, and this week tried to add a vlc server application. That seems to have broken something, as I now have the warning bar that indicates a "serious problem." Digging around it seems to be a failed to load the package list error. So I searched through the forums and found some solutions. Those don't seem to be helping me, though. Here's my latest attempt at fixing this through the terminal

https://www.dropbox.com/s/eyn2joo3jwvx3rz/Screenshot%20from%202014-08-15%2016%3A44%3A45.png

Here's the error window I get. It seems to have some extra information, but I can't seem to find the file it refers to. (sorry - I can't post the actual images; just a link)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yydviv42sjajbz2/Screenshot%20from%202014-08-13%2020%3A00%3A24.png

I'd be really grateful if someone might point me in a good direction for fixing this. My linux knowledge is fairly limited. Thanks!

Comment: You seem to have posted some HTML code into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list`, probably by saving an HTML page. Please post the output of the command `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` in the question.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Here's what that yields: server@server:~$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
[sudo] password for server: 
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list: No such file or directory

Comment: Eek. Typo. According to the pic, that's `mediabuntu.list`, not `medibuntu.list`. This is why I hate screenshots.

Comment: Lol - I was actually wondering that, but didn't trust my linux sense enough to ask... Anyway, here's what that yielded:  
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http://www.mediabuntu.org/sources.list.d/trusty.list"/></head><body><script type="text/javascript">window.location="http://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL="+escape(window.location)+"&r="+escape(document.referrer);</script></body></html>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You tried to fetch `http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/trusty.list`, and made a typo to `http://www.mediabuntu.org/sources.list.d/trusty.list`. The program (or the ISP) you used to obtain it saw that this domain doesn't exist, and sent you down a DNS Search website. It's more likely to be your ISP, since the website says *Time Warner Cable*. This created an HTML file, which caused the syntax errors. Note that `www.medibuntu.org` doesn't exist either, which brings me to:
2. Medibuntu is dead: [The Medibuntu Project has come to an end - what do I do now?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356794/the-medibuntu-project-has-come-to-an-end-what-do-i-do-now) In most cases, you don't need it anymore, and are better off installing packages from the official repos.

For the moment, delete the Medibuntu source:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mediabuntu.list
```

Comment: It worked!!! You, sir (or madam) have made my Monday. Thank you so much for your time and mad skills!

Comment: Oh yeah - sorry, not familiar with this forum. Done.